# How can I make dir inside docker image?

Tags: docker, mkdir, certbot

Why i get error?

Dockerfile

```
FROM certbot/certbot

WORKDIR /
RUN mkdir -p /etc/letsencrypt/live
RUN cd /etc/letsencrypt/live
```

`docker build --no-cache .`

> /bin/sh: cd: line 1: can't cd to /etc/letsencrypt/live: No such file
> or directory

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [Docker Hub `certbot/certbot` page](https://hub.docker.com/r/certbot/certbot/), click on "Tags", and select one of the tags, you can get an automated dump of the build sequence for the image.  Of note, that contains a line

```
VOLUME [/etc/letsencrypt /var/lib/letsencrypt]
```

A directory that's marked as a `VOLUME` in a Dockerfile can't be subsequently modified by `RUN` commands, even in a derived image; changes will just be discarded.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you may try to add there an empty file from outside into that directory

```
ADD readme.txt /etc/letsencrypt/live/readme.txt
```